# How to extract selected fields from a collection in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

From this collection, I just want to extract email and user_name. Please help me out with this.

```
db.users.find().pretty();

{

    "_id" : ObjectId("5c0fe724a16bb04744d295fc"),
    "email" : "any@anything.com",
    "user_name" : "anyone",
    "password" : "anything",
    "timestamp" : ISODate("2018-12-11T16:34:44.487Z"),
    "__v" : 0
}
```

Answer (score 0):

the `.find()` query takes two arguments. The first argument specifies the query. To return all users, pass an empty object `{}`. the second argument specifies a "projection" or the fields you'd like to return from the document that is found in the query.

`db.users.find({ } ,{ "email":1, "user_name":1, "_id":0 })`

You can learn more about the `.find` query on collections and the options that can be passed to it here https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.find/index.html